# Winapi: getting font informations

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, controls

So I made an application using winapi, and I have a few static controls I didn't set any font for. When I saw how the text inside these static controls looks like I decided default font for winapi controls is just fine, and didn't set any other font with WM_SETFONT message for them. Being inexperienced programmer it didn't occur to me that other users could have set completely different default fonts for controls in their systems, depending, for example, on locale they have set. And when I gave my app to some of my friends for tests, I noticed they have completely different font in static controls I didn't touch with WM_SETFONT messages. Conclusion seems to be clear: I have to set this fine-looking font for these controls myself. The problem is, I have no idea what that font could be. I don't feel like testing every font I have in my system and see if it matches, so I wonder if there's any way how to learn which default font is set for controls when they are created. I've heard of WM_GETFONT message, but it just returns the font handle to be used in my application, when what I am looking for is specific information about font so I could set it myself with WM_SETFONT.
That being said - is there any way to know what are default parameters of font that's set for windows and controls that were just created with CreateWindow / CreateWindowEx functions, so I could use these information and choose / create font with these parameters and set it for controls myself?

Comment: Different Windows versions use different default fonts.  It makes very little sense to write the code to find out what the default font is and then change it if you don't like the default.  Just make the choice right away.  If you have no idea what to pick then [this should help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web).

Comment: Users choose fonts based on personal preference. Don't ignore that. Simply use what they have chosen. Dialog resource dimension use DLU's (dialog logical units) that are based off of the font in use. If the dialog is displayed for a user with a different default font, it will automatically adapt, to account for different font metrics.

Comment: Yeah but what I was thinking about was how to check details for default font that are set up in my system for new controls. Nevermind that anyway, I just found and implemented another font which also looks quite decent.

Comment: To get details about the default font used in a dialog call [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947.aspx) with a `SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS` parameter. Picking another font that *"looks quite decent"* may not look so decent on someone else's system.